# Carbon Copy Cloner and FileVault Volumes

Tags: macos, backup, ssd, filevault

I am about to get my SSD back from an RMA process.

I currently have my backup HDD and I'm considering utilizing FileVault's full disk encryption. I'd like to minimize the number of writes before I get the SSD back in my machine.

Can I enable FileVault on both drives, then Carbon Copy Clone the HDD -> SSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replied earlier with an answer without noticing you had tagged it as Lion related; take a look at this **[document](http://help.bombich.com/kb/advanced-strategies/the-disk-center#fde)**, it should answer most of your questions.

From the Developer of CCC:

↘ [link](http://help.bombich.com/discussions/questions/4803-ccc-and-filevault-under-lion#comment_9933321)

> Is there any possibility to have the backup on my other second drive be encrypted?
>
> **Yes, you can enable encryption on your backup volume, or reformat it
>   as encrypted using Disk Utility:**
>
> Full Disk Encryption (Lion only)
>
> **CCC fully supports Lion's Full Disk Encryption.**